# How to enable the Research Assistant in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I created an empty project in Xcode and have added all of my source code files to it.
I do not have any build options/configurations set since the project was empty and I use my old Makefile from the command-line to build the app. Everything works - but...

My problem is that it is a tad annoying not to have the information at my fingertips since the Research Assistant isn't showing any information at all!

The Research Assistant is shown but it doesn't show any information, I guess that it must be instructed to so somehow - but how? Is there a way to enable the Research Assistant and how?? Also, note that I have all the documentation available (but not from the Research Assistant)!

Thanks in advance!
/John

Answer (score 2):

When using Xcode with Research Assistant displayed, I find it only shows info when you highlight something in your code.  For example, if you had:

```
NSString *foo;
```

And you highlighted (clicked on) NSString then the Research Assistant will give you definitions of NSString, the API is belongs in, etc.

Comment: Normally yes, but not in my originally empty project to which I have added my files. But I have no build rules etc...
What settings do I need to turn on in order to activate RA??

Comment: I don't remember turning on any specific settings.  There is a thread on the Apple forums here: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1490892 follow the link in the article to find more details on how others fixed this.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link Mark, but it did not help me :-(

Comment: Ok, I tried to create a new simple iPhone project and then removing all of the project files, instead of creating an empty project.
Then I added my original files to it and when I started editing - WHAM - the Research Assistant immediately showed all the gory details for all the symbols! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem is kind of solved.

I tried to create a new simple iPhone project and then removed all of the included project files, instead of creating an empty project. Then I added my original files to the project and when I started editing - WHAM - the Research Assistant immediately showed all the gory details for all the symbols! :-)

But it is rather annoying to not know how to fix this manually from an empty project...

/John

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to write your own build scripts for an iPhone app?

Comment: We have a pretty large code base for an old iPhone project, that is pre-official-sdk, that uses lots of undocumented stuff and none of the fancy View-Controller classes and all GUI stuff is made programmatically.
However, when adding new stuff, we use the public API, hence the need of easy access RA

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can add your own items to the Xcode help system, and they will be displayed in the research assistant.

http://developer.apple.com/tools/creatingdocsetswithdoxygen.html